# Overheating Arduino Nano: decoupling capacitor advice

Tags: arduino, led, led-driver, decoupling-capacitor, step-down

I've put together a circuit to control two LEDS ([datasheet](http://www.jstronic.com/uploads/2017726102757947.pdf)) with two Picobuck LED drivers ([product page](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13705), [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/AL8805.pdf)) controlled by an Arduino Nano clone. I'm powering the Picobucks with a 12V 5A power supply, which I am also using to power the Nano through a Pololu 5V step down converter ([product page](https://www.pololu.com/product/2831/resources), [datasheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J842/isl85410-datasheet.pdf)). Fritzing sketch attached.

[image]

The problem I am facing is that the Nano has overheated and stopped working - when I touch the processor it is very hot, and no longer controls the Picobuck LED drivers (although they still work fine in themselves, so no problem there.) The Nano is no longer readable when conected up to PC via USB and I also cannot burn the bootlader to it, so it's probably fried. I believe the problem occurred even when no LEDs were connected to the Picobucks, so I assume power to the Nano is the issue.

My question is, have I done something fundamentally wrong in how I am powering the Arduino? Should I perhaps be using a capacitor in the power to the Nano and if so, how?

I am considering using an [Arduino Uno](https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-uno-rev3) instead, because I have read that they have decoupling capacitors built in. Would this perhaps solve the problem, if indeed the power supply to the nano is the problem?

Comment: I think its not about decoupling caps. except for the very rare, cheap, unknown boards, many development boards (including arduinos and clones) have decoupling caps. the problem would be reverse polarity of supply or the stress on the boards regulator that has damaged it and shorted it.

Comment: At least in your drawing, you have the +/- connection for the picobuck boards inversed.

Comment: Did you wire it exactly like your picture? The first Picobuck has V+ and V- swapped. Decoupling seems doubtfull to me but you could try connecting a 10 uF cap in parallel with +5v and Gnd on the nano.

Comment: Other than the above, I see no obvious problems. Can you check that your step-down converter is really outputting only 5V and that the current on the digital pins is in the mA range?

Comment: Aside from the one swapped +/- looks basically okay. Did you measure the 5V output before connecting it? Any momentary short of an Ardunio GPIO or 5V supply pin to +12 will fry it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ground loop: picobucks are connected to ground directly with a wire, and through the arduino with other wires. So if one of the power ground wires to the picobucks comes loose, the whole LED current will flow through the other wire. This would be unfortunate, because the way the grounds are connected on both sides of the arduino board would force this current to flow through the PCB, which probably means a tiny track.

I'd recommend building the whole thing over a piece of blank PCB used as ground plane, and solder all the GND connections to it to get a solid low impedance ground that won't come off (unlike screw terminals).

Another failure mode would be the GND wire coming off one of the picobucks, which means it would only be connected to +12V and the arduino output. This would set its input to an undefined voltage, maybe more than the 5V that the arduino can tolerate. So it would be a good idea to insert a resistor between the arduino output and picobuck input to limit current in case trouble happens, for example 10kOhm.

Make sure the picobucks still work becore trying a new arduino.